# Laravel 5.3 Routes are not working - boilerpate repo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am using latest repo of laravelboilerplate i got this error on server. but it works fine on homestead.

I try to user clear:cache but its the same.

```
UnexpectedValueException in Route.php line 646:
Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Takeaway\addOnCategory\AddOnCategoryTableController]
```

**and here is the code in controller**

```
<code>
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Takeaway\AddOnCategory;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repositories\Backend\Takeaway\AddOnCategory\AddOnCategoryRepository;
use Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

/**
 * Class UserTableController
 */
class AddOnCategoryTableController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    protected $addOnCategory;

    /**
     * @param UserRepository $users
     */
    public function __construct(AddOnCategoryRepository $addOnCategory)
    {
        $this->addOnCategory = $addOnCategory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ManageUserRequest $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __invoke() {

        return Datatables::of($this->addOnCategory->getForDataTable())
            ->addColumn('actions', function($addOnCategory) {
                return $addOnCategory->action_buttons;
            })
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

**and here is the code in route**

```
<code>
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => 'takeaway',
    'as'         => 'takeaway.',
    'namespace'  => 'Takeaway\addOnCategory',
], function() {

    /**
     * Settings Specific Functionality
     */


    /**
     * User CRUD
     */

    Route::resource('/addOnCategory', 'AddOnCategoryController');
    Route::get('addOnCat/get', 'AddOnCategoryTableController')->name('addOnCategory.get');
});
```

Comment: Did you installed laravelcollective/html  ?

Comment: Route::get('addOnCat/get', '__invoke@AddOnCategoryTableController')->name('addOnCategory.get');  add ur methode before controller in route

Comment: yes i did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the name of your method with `AddOnCategoryTableController`

Just try like this

```
Route::get('addOnCat/get', 'AddOnCategoryTableController@__invoke')->name('addOnCategory.get');
```